# ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi for wsgi server setting

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I am setting with djano and uwsgi

`$uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini`

My Django root is here `/var/www/html/myapp/current`

It must be  quite simple setting however I am not sure the yet.

I have these two files

`/var/www/html/myapp/current/myapp/settings.py`
`/var/www/html/myapp/current/myapp/wsgi.py`

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/var/www/html/myapp/current #it success
module=myapp.wsgi:application #it success
env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings # it success
http-socket = 0.0.0.0:8008
processes = 1
threasds = 1
master = 1
max-requests = 100000
```

The error is below, but I can't dig the detailed logs.

```
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 27353, cores: 1)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 27353|app: -1|req: -1/1] 172.17.1.143 () {28 vars in 334 bytes} [Thu Mar 26 17:37:01 2020] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

And this error occurs.

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myapp/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1705)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 1706, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 1707)
```

error happens here

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

Also I am using `anaconda3`

`$conda activate py37` then

start this command

`$uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini`

Comment: `module=myapp.wsgi:application` -- this doesn't look right. It should be just `module=myapp.wsgi`. And value of `chdir` should be the path to your project directory.

Comment: Thank you very much I changed `module` and `chdir` is correct. but keep errors

Comment: Do you have django installed? If you want to use virtualenv, you can set this variable in the config file -- `home = /path/to/virtualenv/`. If you're not using virtualenv, then you'll have to install django system-wide.

Comment: mmmm I see, I am using  anaconda, but when I start the server I enable `conda activate py37` in advance to start server `(py37)$ubuntu:/var/www/html/myapp/current$ uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini`

Comment: Also django is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem , the problem was uwsgi itself.

My setting file was ok.

install uwsgi by `conda`

`conda install -c conda-forge libiconv`

`conda install -c conda-forge uwsgi`

then start uwsgi `/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/py37/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini`